# Can I Use a Transformer to feed a Mains current to a RPI GPIO pin

Tags: transformer, raspberry-pi, mains, current-limiting, input

I have a standard mains (240v) motion detector that activates an outdoors lamp. I want to notify my Raspberry Pi when the lamp is activated.

My plan is to use a 240v to 3.3v transformer that I have already purchased. I intend to wire the transformer in parallel to the feed wire of the lamp so that when the lamp is activated, so too is the transformer and thus the GPIO pin can get its 3.3v activation signal. The transformer output is specified at 3.3V dc 1A 3W (Hi-Link HLK-PM03). I read that you should never source or sink more than 0.5 mA into an input pin.

Is it safe for me to connect this transformer directly to the GPIO pin or do I need to add a resistor or do something to limit the power from the transformer?

Comment: Why a transformer? Why not a relay?

Comment: Using a relay was my original idea some months ago. However, I did some searching and found some articles suggesting the best method was to use a transformer.

Comment: Transformers are usually meant for power transfer not for sensing. Sure there are instrumental transformers but the one you listed seems to be a cheap AC-DC converter. I am not an veteran with Mains and am worried about electrical isolation and other safety issues. You'd probably want to design an analog circuit much like this guy did in a similar project: https://hackaday.io/project/26352-detecting-mains-voltagecurrent/details

Comment: Thanks, it looks very interesting. I will study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi-Link HLK-PM03 as mains voltage detector into R'Pi

This will be a very effective solution and much cheaper than a 230/240VAC relay.

One small point, the Hi-Link HLK-PM03 is a small SMPS power supply  ….not a transformer (and even though it will contain a small ferrite transformer).

I'd suggest that you do need to provide a resistive and clamp network on the output of the power supply:

1. To provide a minimum load on the power supply when active
2. To provide a quicker drop in the output voltage when turned off
3. To ensure that the R'Pi input is protected

A Circuit such as this would be effective:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fowJPa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This provides a minimum load on the power supply of about 55mA, and sets the input voltage to the GPIO pin to about 2.75V.

Comment: Thanks jack, I have these parts on order, as it happens, when they arrive I will give it a try and post the feedback.

Comment: I built the device today as per your drawing. Basically, it is ok. My pi didn't explode and using gpio read, I was able to read the state of the pin correctly. However, when I ran a python script using add_event_detect, the results were erratic. So I wrote a simple perl script that uses WiringPi to talk to the pin. Gpio wfi  waits for me to flick the switch, then it sleeps for one second and (gpio) reads the state. Providing I use the sleep, all is well, otherwise, it is erratic. So I have to conclude that the switching process is not clean. But for my system, a second's delay is no problem.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl;

`gpio mode 22 input`;

while (true) {
  `gpio wfi 22 both`;
   sleep 1;
   my $pin_state = `gpio read 22`;
   print "pin state: $pin_state";
} ---- (gpio cmds in backticks ---> results --- pin state: 1
pin state: 0
pin state: 1
pin state: 0
pin state: 1

Comment: Having done some more testing, the switching on and off of some household appliances nearby cause the gpio wfi to trip, however, the pin states don't appear to change so if you use this idea, be sure to write your code to take action only when the pin states change and not on the gpio wfi being tripped.